# Convert object to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched similar questions about converting classes but none have really helped me.

I have a Fraction class and want to simplify it to an int if possible.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        self.simplify()

        if self.denominator == 1:
            # convert self to int of value numerator
```

I have a function within the Fraction class which will simplify the fraction when it is created (2/6 becomes 1/3, etc.)

```
    def simplify(self):
        div = gcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator //= div
        self.denominator //= div
```

My current solution to this problem is as follows:

```
def convert(fraction):
    if fraction.denominator == 1:
        return fraction.numerator  # int
    else:
        return fraction            # Fraction


f = Fraction(3, 1)
f = convert(f)
```

I'm using these fractions in various algebraic expressions so I would like them to be as simple as possible. eg. 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 (instead of 1/1)

Is there any way I can convert the Fraction object into an int without having to pass it through this external function every time?

Thanks

Comment: Even if this were possible, I don't think this would be recommended. I can see dynamically changing the type of an object making code hard to reason about. The fact that `convert` returns two different types isn't ideal either though. Won't you need to do a manual type check before you can use the return value?

Comment: Do you know that python already provides a Fraction class? It may help you: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fractions.html

Comment: yes, also think that dynamically changing the type of your object is not the right way to go.

Comment: Carcigenicate, the convert function was just something I threw together to demonstrate what Im trying to accomplish. My classes can handle both ints and fractions as inputs. (for nested fractions, etc.)

Comment: MiguelSR, the built in fraction class isn't flexible enough for what I plan to do. It will eventually handle unknown terms eg. 2x^2. I wasn't aware of the class beforehand though so thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do:

- It is not optimal to have a function which returns two different types, so you could handle the conversion with a class method.
- It would help if the conversion was supported in the print() func as well

With that in mind, I just moved convert inside the class, and added a **str** method as well.

```
from fractions import gcd

class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        self.simplify()

    def __str__(self):
        if self.denominator == 1:
            return str(self.numerator)
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.numerator,self.denominator)

    def simplify(self):
        div = gcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator //= div
        self.denominator //= div
    def convert(fraction):
        if fraction.denominator == 1:
            return fraction.numerator  # int
        return fraction # Fraction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Fraction(6, 2)
    c = Fraction.convert(f)
    print(f)
    print(c)
    f2 = Fraction(3, 4)
    print(f2)
```

See if it can help you.

Comment: I agree it isn't good to have a function that returns 2 types, this was just to see if having an object convert its class was possible without something like this additional function. I can handle both ints and Fractions so maybe it would just be simpler to change it for the string representation. Thanks for the help.